# A general criterion of convergence of series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, conjectures

Given a non degenerated function $f:\mathbb N^+\to\mathbb Z_2 $. (It doesn't stabilize and become constant for all $n$ larger than some natural number). Define the function $\sigma(i,n,f)=|f^{-1}(i)\cap\mathbb Z_n|\,$ and

$c_n=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
a_{\sigma(o,n,f)}\;\text{ if } f(n)=0\\ 
b_{\sigma(1,n,f)}\;\text{ if } f(n)=1
\end{array}
\right. 
$

Then $(c_n)_n$ is a shuffle of $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ for each function $f$ as above. All the terms $a_i$ and $b_i$ occur exactly once in the sequence $c_1,c_2,\dots$ in preserved index order.

I would like to formulate this conjecture:

If $\displaystyle a=\sum^\infty_{i=1} a_i\;$ and $\displaystyle \; b=\sum^\infty_{i=1} b_i\;$ are convergent and $c_i$ arise from a shuffle of $a_i$ and $b_i$, then $\displaystyle a+b=\sum^\infty_{i=1} c_i$.

I'm asking for a proof of the conjecture or a counterexample and will award the three first correct answers with a bounty worth 200.

Comment: Well, is this a different quesion from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928887/shuffle-infinite-deck? If not, I wonder if the definition of $c_n$ above works...but assuming it does, doesn't (absolute convergence $\iff$ unconditional convergence) answer the question?

Comment: How come your reaction to @daniel's comment is to *delete* the other question? Please explain.

Comment: @Did, because the other question was about something else and I found the answer my self and no one  seemed interested and because I have bad experience about faulty closing for duplicates. I can reopen if there are good reasons for it.

Comment: @daniel, I know that conditional convergence depends on the order of the terms and that any result can be found by *permuting* the terms. But I think *shuffling* two conditional convergent series gives a convergent series. Else there must be some counterexample.

Comment: If we add the alternating harmonic series to itself, we get $2\log 2.$ But if we accept that the Riemann series theorem gives a shuffle of the original series (to use your term) that will diverge, we can certainly find one for the sum. I'm not sure how easy it would be to exhibit one.

Comment: @daniel, I can't follow your reasoning. Please elaborate!

Comment: @daniel: do you mean $a_n=b_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @daniel. Then which shuffle function $f$ did you have in mind?

Comment: If $1+1/3+1/5...$ diverges, then choose enough terms so they exceed 1/2 by 1. Then add -1/2. Then write enough terms so they exceed 1/4 by 1 and then add -1/4. You have 1+1+1...

Comment: @daniel. It might work.

Comment: @daniel. I wonder what happens if $f$ correspond to $(1,0,1,0000,1,000000000,1,0000000000000000,1\dots)$?

Comment: Not sure--maybe you could show that. But the method above, if correct, is basically a proof that the shuffle can diverge--a counterexample. I guess there are infinitely many shuffles that work. Getting a particular formula is more labor and arguably not as interesting.

Comment: @mercio is right, alas, my example is not a shuffle. i flagged my answer and i think a mod can undo your acceptance/upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forall $n$, $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i = \sum_{i=1}^{\sigma(0,n,f)} a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{\sigma(1,n,f)} b_i$.

Since $\sum_{i=1}^\sigma a_i$ converges to $a$ as $\sigma \to \infty$ and $\sigma(0,n,f)$ diverges to infinity as $n \to \infty$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\sigma(0,n,f)} a_i$ converges to $a$ as $n \to \infty$.

Similarly, $\sum_{i=1}^{\sigma(1,n,f)} b_i$ converges to $b$, and so $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$ converges to $a+b$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: It seems like my "criterion" is more like a notice.